# Where a thread object is created in stack or in heap memory?

Tags: java, java-threads

Actually I was asked this question recently in an interview , I answered stack , am I right as I thought that threads would be executing methods, but could you please explain as why threads get created in stack or if not then why is it created in heap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The following link may clarify your doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433523/where-is-thread-object-created-stack-or-heap

Comment: All objects are created on heap, including `Thread` objects.

Comment: A Thread object is always created on the heap (unless it is not started)

Most objects are created on the heap (as that is what it is for) but in some cases when an object can be determined by Escape Analysis to have not escaped a method, it can place the object on the stack.  In the case of Thread this isn't possible unless it is not actually started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between **heap** memory and **stack** memory is that stack memory is used to store local variables and function calls while heap memory is used to store objects in Java. No matter where the object is created in code.

So Thread objects stored in heap.

Also Each Thread has its own stack to hold own local variables and function calls.